# How to add ::before element to the input

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I'm new to web development. I'm trying to add before element for input in form but it doesn't work. Maybe someone knows why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `<input />` cannot have any contents. You cannot use `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements on this element. Consider wrapping it using `<span>` or `<div>` and give an `display: inline-block` style to them and use `::after` or `::before`.

```css
div,
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

div:before,
span:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #f90;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span><input /></span>
<div><input /></div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Read More:** This question: [Can I use a :before or :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587669) shows more information.